# basic sql employee

Tags: sql, oracle

The employee table (EMP) specifies groups by department code, the sum of salaries by group, the average (constant treatment), and the number of people in each group's salary, and is presented below, listed in department code order. I would like to modify the following SQL syntax to look up departments whose average salary exceeds 2800000.

```
 SELECT
    DEPT
    , SUM(SALARY) 합계
    , FLOOR(AVG(SALARY)) 평균
    , COUNT(*) 인원수
    FROM
    EMP
    GROUP BY
    DEPT
    ORDER BY DEPT ASC;
```

question 1. Conditions that need to be modified

question 2. What should I add to the presented code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below sql:

```
SELECT
    DEPT
    , SUM(SALARY) 합계
    , FLOOR(AVG(SALARY)) 평균
    , COUNT(*) 인원수
    FROM
    EMP
    GROUP BY
    DEPT having FLOOR(AVG(SALARY) > 2800000
    ORDER BY DEPT ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't read your aliases so I'll just presume what they mean.

If query - you posted in the question - works OK, then use it as a CTE and select desired data from it:

```
with data as
  (select dept, 
          sum(salary) sumsal,
          floor(avg(salary)) avgsal,
          count(*) cnt
   from emp
   group by dept
  )
select *
from data
where avgsal > 2800000;
```

Comment: That works.  But I'm guessing this is a homework question and I'm guessing that the intent of the question was to have the student use the `having` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter aggregated  result using having

```
    SELECT
        DEPT
        , SUM(SALARY) 합계
        , FLOOR(AVG(SALARY)) 평균
        , COUNT(*) 인원수
        FROM
        EMP
        GROUP BY     DEPT
        HAVING AVG(SALARY) >2800000
        ORDER BY DEPT ASC;
```